# How do I use predict() on new data for lme4::glmer model?

Tags: r, predict, lme4, mixed-models

I have been trying to establish predictive performance (AUC ROC) for a glmer model. When I try and use the `predict()` function on a test data set, the output for this function is the length of my train data set.

```
    folds = 10;
    glmerperf=rep(0,folds); glmperf=glmerperf;

    TB_Train.glmer.subset <- TB_Train.glmer %>% select(one_of(subset.vars), IDNO)


    TB_Train.glmer.fs <- TB_Train.glmer.subset[,c(1:7, 22)]
    TB_Train.glmer.ns <- TB_Train.glmer.subset[, 8:21]
    TB_Train.glmer.cns <- TB_Train.glmer.ns %>% scale(center=TRUE, scale=TRUE) %>% cbind(TB_Train.glmer.fs)

    foldsamples = caret::createFolds(TB_Train.glmer.cns$Case.Status, k = folds, list = TRUE, returnTrain = FALSE)

    for (n in 1:folds)
    {
      testdata = TB_Train.glmer.cns[foldsamples[[n]],]
      traindata = TB_Train.glmer.cns[-foldsamples[[n]],]

      GLMER <- lme4::glmer(Case.Status ~ .  + (1 | IDNO), data = traindata, family="binomial", control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=1000000)))
      glmer.probs <- predict(GLMER, newdata=testdata$Non.TB.Case, type="response")
      glmer.ROC <- roc(predictor=glmer.probs, response=testdata$Case.Status, levels=rev(levels(testdata$Case.Status)))
      glmerperf[n] <- glmer.ROC$auc
    }

    prob <- predict(GLMER,  newdata=TB_Test.glmer$Non.TB.Case, type="response", re.form=~(1|IDNO))

    print(sprintf('Mean AUC ROC of model on test set for GLMER %f', mean(glmerperf)))
```

Both the `prob` and `glmer.probs` objects are the length of the `traindata` object, despite specifying the `newdata` argument. I have noticed issues with the predict function in the past, but none as specific as this one.

Also, when the model is run, I get several errors about needing to scale my data (which I already have) and that the model fails to converge. Any ideas on how to fix this? I have already bumped up the iterations and selected a new optimizer.

Comment: `newdata` should be a dataframe not a vector, so using something like `testdata[, "Non.TB.Case", drop=FALSE]` instead of your existing `newdata` argument might help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. I understand that I should predict from a data frame and I want predictions for the variable `testdata$Case.Status`, but when I run code like this `prob <- predict(GLMER,  newdata=TB_Test.glmer[, "Case.Status", drop=FALSE], type="response", re.form=~(1|IDNO))` I get the following error `Error in terms.formula(formula(x, fixed.only = TRUE)) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument`. If I try to manipulate as you mentioned, I get this error `Error in `[.data.frame`(TB_Test.glmer, , "Non.TB.Case", drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: Could the error be referring to my use of a "." to denote all variables?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that error was arising from using the "." shortcut to specify all predictors for the model.